# MS Project VBA - How To Find Currently Active Task Filter?

Tags: vba, filter, ms-project

I want to create a toggle to switch in a filter (using FilterApply Name:="fName") and back again how ever I can not seem to find a way to check what filter is applied currently.

Does any one know of a way to query what is the currently active filter with the MS API ?

Thanks

Terran

```
    Sub _Unbaselined_Tasks_View()

  ---> Problem Line If ActiveProject.TaskFilter = "Active Tasks With No Baseline" Then
            FilterApply Name:="All Tasks"
            FilterClear
    Else
        FilterApply Name:="Active Tasks With No Baseline"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you always filter the same column?

Comment: Terran please add the code to your question with the edit button under the tags. It's impossible to understand it on comments.

Comment: Hi Damian - I have added that code to the first page. Thanks T

Comment: What's the problem with the code that you have? What is the value of `ActiveProject.TaskFilter`?

Comment: Hi Nick - although it seems to me ou can do a lot you can not ask which filter is active hence the looking for a work around - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.filteredit - Thanks T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [project object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project) has a property called [CurrentFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.currentfilter) which will return the name of the filter applied or "All Tasks" if no filter is applied.

```
Sub Elite_Unbaselined_Tasks_View()

    If ActiveProject.CurrentFilter = "Active Tasks With No Baseline" Then
        FilterApply Name:="All Tasks"
        FilterClear
    Else
        FilterApply Name:="Active Tasks With No Baseline"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank youy that works & I have marked it as the annswer.